# infinity equals infinity equals infinity

Tags: meaning-in-context

I do not understand the bold part of the paragraph found below. Can anyone help please?

the Russian mathematician Ludwig Phillip Cantor demonstrated that there are an infinite number of numbers just between 0 and 1 and **more than one kind of infinity – the countable and the uncountable: infinity equals infinity equals infinity and independent of dimension**, as the mind-defying proposition goes.

(Art and Science by Sian Ede)

Comment: Countable infinity is infinity on the domain of all integers, and uncountable infinity is infinity on the domain of all real numbers. Maybe it means that both types of infinity, countable and uncountable, have the same abstract value?

Comment: Is your problem understating the mathematics or the English? For the maths - post the question on http://mathematics.stackexchange.com; for the English - you need to understand the maths first - the English then makes perfect sense.

Comment: @user127733 , the fault is not in your understanding, the fault is in the original text, which is (1) trying to say too many things in one sentence & (2) trying to simplify too much. Result : a statement which is (A) incomprehensible & (B) false.

Comment: Yes, "infinity equals infinity equals infinity" is nonsense.

Comment: Reminds me of a type of word play by Gertrude Stein, I think: A rose is a rose is a rose.

Answer (score 5):

As with everything Ede writes, what's understandable is wrong, and the rest is incomprehensible.  The full name of the famous mathematician is Georg Ferdinand Ludwig Philipp Cantor.  For his mathematical work, he is always referenced as "Georg Cantor."  Although Cantor was born in St Petersburg, he moved to Germany when he was eleven, attended school in Germany, rose through the ranks of the German educational apparat, and published exclusively in German.  His work on set theory and the controversy it generated was a part of the German mathematical milieu of the late 19th century.

Cantor did not demonstrate there are an infinite number of numbers between 0 and 1.  This fact is obvious to anyone who realizes that there are an infinite number of integers.  (The proof is left to the interested reader.)  Cantor showed that the integers and the real numbers (all the numbers represented by decimal sequences) are not equinumerous, although both sets are infinite.  That is, there are in a precisely-defined way, more real numbers than there are integers.  Cantor also showed that any numeric interval contains an infinite set of numbers, with the set's size larger than the size of the integers.

Cantor didn't just prove that there are two kinds of infinities, countable and uncountable.  He showed that there is a hierarchy of uncountable infinities, each one larger than its predecessor.

The statement "infinity equals infinity equals infinity" is nonsensical on its own, and in fact, in set theoretic terms of set sizes, this is the opposite of what Cantor proved.  The statement "and independent of dimension" is also nonsensical, as "independent" is undefined here.  For what it's worth there are mathematical spaces of countably infinite and uncountably infinite dimensionality.

There are some mind-defying concepts in Cantor's work, which aroused opposition and caused controversy when he published those concepts.  But how could Ede tell?  She doesn't know any mathematics. She knows even less physics.  I can't wait till you get to that part.

Comment: +1 , for [ The statement "infinity equals infinity equals infinity" is **nonsensical** on its own, and in fact, in set theoretic terms of set sizes, this is the **opposite** of what Cantor proved ]

Comment: Deadrat:  See the question "In another oxymoron" for Ede on physics.  Maybe there should be a tag....

Comment: @ab2Yes, that's Ede on classical dynamics.  I was thinking about her ruminations on quantum theory that haven't been questioned yet.  (I've peaked ahead.)

Answer (score 1):

### Maths primer

*This is deliberately **not** mathematically rigorous!*

Cantor showed that there are (at least) two types of infinity - the countable (e.g. counting numbers 1, 2, 3, ...) and the uncountable (e.g. real numbers).

He also showed that all infinite sets in each of those classes were the same cardinality (size - more or less).

So, the set of counting numbers has the same cardinality as the set of all integers (positive & negative & zero) which has the same cardinality as all 2 dimensional points on a 2 dimensional grid or indeed all n dimensional points on an n dimensional grid.

Similarly, there are an infinite number of real numbers between 0 and 1 as there are between 0 and 10,000,000 or between negative infinity and positive infinity. There are as many points on a line 1cm long as there are on a square 1cm x 1cm or inside a 1cm x 1cm x 1cm cube or a 1cm a side 1000 dimensional hypercube etc.

In both cases it is even true that an infinite subset can have the same cardinality as its own superset, that is, an infinite part of an infinite set can be in some ways the same "size" as the original set. It is also possible to construct countably infinite subsets of uncountably infinite sets (e.g. integers from reals) but not the other way around.

### The English

Is trying to get the above concept across.

### Edit

Having read the comments and the other answers I now realise that this is from a supposed work of non-fiction; I thought it was a novel and that the usage was poetic! If you are trying to use this book to lean actual mathematics; don't.

Comment: Thank you so much for your mathematical clarification. It is really useful. But here you are talking about two infinities: countable and uncountable while the sentence "infinity equals infinity equals infinity" has three infinities. Does the third infinity imply "general infinity"? That is, Countable infinity equals uncountable infinity that both equal any other infinity?

Comment: Expunge the sentence "infinity equals infinity equals infinity" from your mind.  It is wrong.  Deadrat's answer is right.  Take a look at Rudy Rucker's book: "Infinity and the Mind."  This will be harder going than the book you now have, possibly too hard, but you need a better book.

Comment: The most generous way of interpreting "infinity equals infinity equals infinity" as true is that the writer was referring to different infinite sets with the same cardinality, like the sets of integers, odd integers, and millions-gers.  Differently cardinal infinities are not equal, which is what Cantor showed.

Comment: I suspect that the part about "independent of dimension" was intended to refer to the fact that the number of points in a one-dimensional line segment equals the number of points in a two-dimensional region and also equals the number of points in a three-dimensional volume. For *these* three infinities it is the case that all three are equal.  But the quoted text sounds as if *all* infinities are equal, and that is wrong.